# Chrome custom tabs: Why is CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService() not working correctly?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to implement chrome custom tabs, but I'm getting the following runtime error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nirvan.customtabsexample/com.example.nirvan.customtabsexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsClient.warmup(long)' on a null object reference
```

Here's my code:

```
 CustomTabsClient mClient;
    String packageName = "com.android.chrome";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Binds to the service.
        CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(this, packageName, new CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onCustomTabsServiceConnected(ComponentName name, CustomTabsClient client) {
                // mClient is now valid.
                Log.e("TAG","onCustumServiceConnected");
                mClient = client;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                // mClient is no longer valid. This also invalidates sessions.
                Log.e("TAG","onServiceDisconnected");
                mClient = null;
            }
        });


        mClient.warmup(0);


        CustomTabsSession session = mClient.newSession(new CustomTabsCallback());
        session.mayLaunchUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"), null, null);


        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = "https://www.facebook.com/";
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(url));
            }
        });






    }
```

The app crashes as soon as it starts. Also, I'm not getting any of the 2 log outputs, so the two methods under `CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService()` are never being called. What could the problem be?
    I think it's the package name i'm passing to `CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService()` . I didn't know what to pass so I passed `"com.android.chrome"`. Is this what's wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` at the following line:

```
mClient.warmup(0);
```

The reason for this is that once you invoke `CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService`, the callback will run asynchronously. When the call to warmup happens, there wasn't enough time for the service to connect and assign a value to `mClient`. Move the warmup call and mayLaunchUrl to inside the onConnected callback, and it should work.

```
    // Binds to the service.
    CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(this, packageName, new CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onCustomTabsServiceConnected(ComponentName name, CustomTabsClient client) {
            // mClient is now valid.
            Log.e("TAG","onCustomTabsServiceConnected");
            mClient = client;
            mClient.warmup(0);
            CustomTabsSession session = mClient.newSession(new CustomTabsCallback());
            session.mayLaunchUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"), null, null);

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // mClient is no longer valid. This also invalidates sessions.
            Log.e("TAG","onServiceDisconnected");
            mClient = null;
        }
    });
```