# Android CustomTabs bindCustomTabsService and onCustomTabsServiceConnected never called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-customtabs

I am trying to setup `CustomTabs` in an activity; however, the `bindCustomTabsService` method never calls `onCustomTabsServiceConnected`. What am I missing?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)


        CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(this, "com.android.chrome", object: CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
            override fun onServiceDisconnected(p0: ComponentName?) {

            }

            override fun onCustomTabsServiceConnected(
                name: ComponentName,
                client: CustomTabsClient
            ) {
                // this is never called
                log("Client connected")
                mClient = client
                client.warmup(0L)
            }

        })
        ..........
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44495345/18362930 Try this solution

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb Yes I saw this question; however, it does not appear to be the same issuer I'm having, and it didn't help :/